# Checking a limit equality

Tags: limits

Let's suppose we have a some special point in the $x$ axis. Let me denote it as $x_{\dagger}$. Let us set two points such that,
$x_p = x_{\dagger} + \delta x$ and $x_n = x_{\dagger} - \delta x$,for $\delta x > 0$. Let us also take some random function $f(x)$. From here, can we write

$$\lim_{\delta x \to 0}f(x_p) \equiv \lim_{x \to x_{\dagger}^{+}}f(x_{\dagger})$$

and

$$\lim_{\delta x \to 0}f(x_n) \equiv \lim_{x \to x_{\dagger}^{-}}f(x_{\dagger})$$
?

Comment: You should drop the dagger from the x inside the fs on the right hand sides, but yes

Comment: yes you are right. Thanks for the info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you had the right idea. If you write it like
$$\lim_{\delta x \to 0}f(x_p) \equiv \lim_{x \to x_{\dagger}^{+}}f(x)$$
it is correct. The other case works in the same way.

Comment: Assuming that $\delta x >0$.

Comment: yes you are right, I should have dropped the $\dagger$ symbol.